# Illegal Character and missing ] after element list error

Tags: c#, .net, razor, servicestack

I am using Servicestack to send a custom Object List to Razor View page but i am getting `Illegal Character and missing ] after element list` error.Here is how i am sending from Servicestack Service ..

```
var objSet = new List<Setup>()
{
   new Setup { Id = 1, Code = "73878", Name = "Systems", ContactName = "XYZ", ContactEmail = "info@systems.com", IsActive = true },
   new Setup { Id = 1, Code = "99878", Name = "Microsoft Systems",  ContactName= "Archit",ContactEmail = "enquiry@systems.com" ,IsActive = true }
};

return objSet ;
```

and this is how i am using in Razor View Page..

```
var dataSet = [@{
    foreach(var row in Model)
    {
        <text>[@row.Code,@row.Name,@row.ContactName,@row.ContactEmail]</text>
    }
}];
```

Please help me to resolve this issue..Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried giving different ID?

Comment: you could also try `@{ var objSet = ......}`

Comment: Your code render like var dataSet = [ [73878,Systems,XYZ,info@systems.com] [99878,Microsoft Systems,Archit,enquiry@systems.com] ]; in html page, when you get `Illegal Character` error at your end?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating `<text>` nodes with attributes? Shouldn't it be something like

```
   foreach(var row in Model)
        {
            string.Format("<text Id='{0}' Name='{1}' ConcatName='{2}' ConcatEmail='{3}'/>",row.Code,row.Name,row.ContactName,row.ContactEmail);
        }
```

But I must admit I don't use Razor and I'm not familiar with the syntax you use...